# How to access MacBook mail preview files after the email is closed?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I am using MacOS Sierra 10.12.3 and recently I closed an email account using the Exchange servers. Despite the email account is closed all my email can be previewed in mail. I would like to retrieve all preview data that is stored somewhere on my MacBook. Does anyone know where these preview files are stored?

Comment: Have you looked in `~/Library/Mail/..`?

Comment: I am aware that these preview files are stored under the hidden directory library/mail/V2. However I cannot figure out how the subfolders and files are organized. I hope someone already wrote a code to retrieve these file so that they are simply arranged chronologically under one folder.

Comment: Actually they are all stored under library/mail/V4 (not V2). However I do not understand the organization of the hundreds of subfolders and files.

Comment: Are you trying to save each email as an individual file in a folder on the Mac outside of Mail?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do, save all these data outside mail, preferably in chronologically order.

Comment: Since the email account is closed I would like to keep these past email messages in one folder just in case I need to refer to them to support possible future claims.

Answer (score 1):

Open mail and then export all the messages to a file in the .mbox standard format.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19174

There is wide support for parsing that file format or importing it into other clients if you wish. Apple's format changes for time to time and is optimized for tasks other than easy parsing like spotlight search, minimizing file system changes for time machine, etc...

Comment: Exporting the mailbox will not work in this case as the Exchange mailbox has been closed. Only the preview for all mail remain on my computer. The mail files are empty.